# Handle POST and GET Mehtods in the same view with Django and Full Calendar JS

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

first, sorry for my bad english, i'm very redundant with my explanations because i'm newbie in this programming languaje and this community.

So, let's begin, I have mounted all structure for the full calendar itself and I use a modal pop-up when I click on a empty space in a date to add a new event and works perfectly adding events to my model and rendering in JSON, the real question is: how I can do to update an existing event when I click on it?, here is my code:

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from apps.calendarDCC.forms import EventForm
from apps.calendarDCC.models import EventsCalendar
import json

def show_calendar(request):
    return render(request, 'calenar/events_fullcalendar.html')#to show the calendar

def json_events(request):
    events = EventsCalendar.objects.all().values('id', 'title', 'description', 'start', 'end', 'className', 'editable', 'allDay', 'customer').order_by('id')
    events_list = list(events)
    return JsonResponse(events_list, safe=False)#render my events in JSON

def modal_addevent(request): #use 'Eventform' in a modal to add events
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return redirect('events_calendar')
else:
    form = EventForm()
return render(request, 'events/events_calendar.html', {'form':form})
```

my template in HTML

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="col" id= "calendar">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
                locale: 'en',
                //timezone: 'local',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
                handleWindowResize: true, 
                header: { 
                    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear, today', 
                    center: 'title',  
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,list' 
                },
                events: '/calendar/json/events', #the url with JSON coded events
                editable: true, 
                navLinks: true, 
                nowIndicator: true, 
                weekNumbers: true, 
                eventLimit: true, 
                selectable: true, 
                displayEventTime: true,
                dayClick:function(date,jsevent,view){
                    $("#ModalAddEvents").modal(); // calls the modal to add events with ‘EventForm’
                },
                eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){
                    // here is where I need help, how to edit an existing event and save to my model?
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<!--modal(Add events to the calendar)-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAddEvents" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add a new event!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <br/>
            <div></div>
            <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-success" href="{{ 'events_calendar' }}">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried everything that I imagine to do that, but without any answer and after two weeks of unsatisfying efforts I decided to post a question here, please show me the way! and be gentle to this newbie, let me know if i make a mess with this question.

Thanks.

Comment: how about share your git repo since your question is a little bit complicated?

Comment: maybe you can fix html code error first: 1. <form method="post" action="{{url_of_events_calendar}}"> and
2. <button type="submit">

Comment: sorry, i'm very bad to explain my questions or answers, i dont work with GIT unfortunately, let me reduce my long question:

I want to do a view that handle the POST and GET methods, i have a view that handle POST of new events but i need to have the posiblility to edit  an event when i click on it, i've tried everything but nothing works.

Thanks a lot for take the time to answer my question and let me know if this reduced question its less complicated.

Comment: Thanks I do the corrections in my HTML template, I'm still working to find the answer.